# Proof review: If $A$ is an event, then $A$ uniquely determines $I_A$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, functions, proof-verification, random-variables

I came encountered the following statement:

> If $A$ is an event, then $A$ uniquely determines $I_A$ and vice versa (to get from $I_A$ back to $A$, we can use the fact that $A = \{ s \in S : I_A (s) = 1 \})$.

So, according to this statement, any event is uniquely determined by its indicator random variable, and the indicator random variable of any event is uniquely determined by its event.

My proof for part 1 ($A$ is an event $\Rightarrow$ $A$ uniquely determines $I_A$) would proceed as follows:

---

**Proof:**

Let $A$ be an event of the sample space $S$.

Therefore, $A \subseteq S$.

Let $I$ and $J$ be indicator random variables such that

$$I (s)={\begin{cases}1&{\text{if }}s\in A,\\0&{\text{if }}s\notin A.\end{cases}}$$

and

$$J (s)={\begin{cases}1&{\text{if }}s\in A,\\0&{\text{if }}s\notin A.\end{cases}}$$

*(I have not studied measure theory, so, for the purpose of this proof, I'm just going to go ahead and assume that indicator random variables are the same thing as [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), and I'm further going to assume that indicator functions are indeed [functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)).)*

Therefore, since $I$ and $J$ are functions, we have that $I = \{ (s, I(s)) : s \in S \}$ and $J = \{ (s, J(s)) : s \in S \}$.

Without loss of generality, let $s_n \in I$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore $s_n \in S$. And therefore, $s_n \in J$.

And finally, since $s_n \in I$ and $s_n \in J$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we must have that $I = J$. And therefore, $I(s) = J(s)$.

Therefore, any event uniquely determines it's indicator random variable.

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really nothing to prove. The indicator function of a set takes on the value $1$ for elements of the set and $0$ otherwise. That description completely describes a function - the only function with that property.

Your "proof" is trying to say that, but there are several places that make no sense at all. For example, in

> Without loss of generality, let $s_n∈I$ for any $n∈N$.
>
> Therefore $s_n∈S$.   And therefore, $s_n∈J $.

This says that something in $I$ is also in $S$. But $I$ is a set of ordered pairs whose first coordinates are elements of $S$. Things in $I$ are not in $S$.

Moreover, you seem to be assuming $I$ (or $S$) is indexed by the natural numbers. $s_n$ is meaningless. (What if $S$ were the set of real numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The real numbers can't be indexed by the natural numbers, right? That was Cantor's thing?

Comment: Right. And there's no need for indexing at all. You can argue that if an object $x$ (which is a pair, not an element of $S$) is in $I$ then it is in $J$. Why try to call it $x_{\text{something}}$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Let $x \in I$ (so $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$). Therefore, $x$ is a 2-tuple with first element in $S$. Given this, we therefore also have that $x \in J$. And so we have that $I = J$ and $I(s) = J(s)$. Therefore, any event uniquely determines it's indicator random variable. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's essentially obvious once you know what an indicator function is, so never formally proved and that's OK.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for taking the time to clarify!